# Customize PayPal buttons inside payment form

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

I m using standard PayPal buttons forms to integrate payment on my website, typically using a "Subscribe" button. I wonder if I can custom this form, for example inserting my own button in the goal of localizing its content, for example for French users.

Am I allowed to do this or the PayPal official forms are mandatory ?

Thanks

Comment: PayPal form components are mandatory.  But you can add your custom parameters in to it.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I localize the buttons content ?

Comment: I am not sure how you want to localize.  But here you can get the French buttons which is PayPal official community.https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/archive/buttons/FR/

Comment: Thanks for this. But I think there is no equivalent of the "subscribe" button in French. It seems that French and English buttons layouts are different, which is pretty bad for my UX

Answer (score 0):

You can find the buttons for french here : 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/archive/buttons/FR/

Or you can use 
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/fr_FR/CH/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif[image]